# How to INSERT a DATE?

Tags: oracle

Hi I am new to Oracle and forgot how to enter a date. I have tried many variations and can't seem to get it, plus I have looked on the internet but can't find the correct example. My table is set up like this: hiredate DATE,  (DATE being I assume the default input, but what is the default).

Thanks for any help.

Here's my code:

```
SQL> SET LINESIZE 120
SQL> SET PAGESIZE 45
SQL> SET FEEDBACK 1
SQL> SET ECHO ON
SQL> 
SQL> DROP TABLE employee
  2  
SQL> CREAT TABLE student
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CREAT TABL..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (
  3  empno    NUMBER(4)CONSTRAINT employee_empno_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  4  empname  VARCHAR(10),
  5  job      VARCHAR(10),
  6  manager  NUMBER(4),
  7  hiredate DATE,
  8  salary   NUMBER(7,2),
  9  commission NUMBER(7,2),
 10  deptno   NUMBER(2)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'President', NULL, 11/17/1981, 5000, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO employee
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values


SQL> VALUES(7839, 'President', NULL, '11/17/1978', 5000, NULL, 10);
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "VALUES(783..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'President', NULL, '11/17/1978', 5000, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO employee
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, 11/17/1981, 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, 11/17/1981, 5000, NULL, 10)
                                              *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, 19811117, 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, 19811117, 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '11/17/1981', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '11/17/1981', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1978/11/17
  3  )
  4  ;
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President' NULL, '1978/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President' NULL, '1978/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00917: missing comma

Hello, I am new to MySQL and forgot how to properly INSERT at DATE when using MySQL Plus. I have tried many different variations as you will be able to see and I can't seem to figure it out. I also looked on the internet but always find examples where they make there own formats. What is the correct way to insert a date when the table was created using: hiredate


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981/17/11', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981/17/11', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/1981', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/1981', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/81', 5000, NULL, 100);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/81', 5000, NULL, 100)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King, 'President', NULL, '11/17/1981', 5000, NULL, 10);
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '11/17/81', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '11/17/81', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/81', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/81', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/17/11', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/17/11', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/81/11', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/81/11', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '81/11/17', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981-11-17', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '1981-11-17', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2   VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/1981', 5000, NULL, 10);
 VALUES(7839, 'King', 'President', NULL, '17/11/1981', 5000, NULL, 10)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: Which one are you using Oracle or Mysql? Please keep only the relevant tag.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man: Agreed, but judging by the `ORA-*` errors, it looks like Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TO_DATE](http://psoug.org/definition/TO_DATE.htm) function:

```
TO_DATE('11/17/1981', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It lets you specify a date as a string and then the format that its in so Oracle can convert it into a Date.

Or you can use a date literal:

`date '1981-11-17'`

Comment: Or even better, use date literals like `date '1981-11-17'`.  [ISO 8601 FTW](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: @jonearles: Thx for the xkcd reference :-).  If using a date literal, Oracle actually expects something of the form `'17-NOV-2013'` (atleast by default).

Comment: That's the typical default for strings that you convert to dates, but that's not a date literal.  A date literal is something like this:  `select date '1981-11-17' from dual;`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH go-oleg!!!!! Your answer worked! And thank you all who took the time to read my post. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Dates are format sensitive in SQL. So you need to enclouse them in single quotes like
('21-Dec-2010'). If your date is not coming in the standard format then you need to convert using Single Row Conversion Function TO_DATE using the specific format model. You can find more of these syntax on my portal here
http://www.suhelsayyad.com/p/blog-page_14.html